# Can't start service with sudo since root user has no access to Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell, ubuntu, rvm, bundler

**tl;dr**
Trying to run a service which needs ruby to run. But, Ruby is installed with [RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/) where the root user can't seem to access it, producting the error `/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory`. `rvmsudo` doesn't work.

**Background**
I have an `init.d` script which is supposed to start a [unicorn server](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/). I keep the script in the `config` directory of my rails application and symlink to it from `/etc/init.d/busables_unicorn`.

```
$ ls -l /etc/init.d/busables_unicorn
-> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   62 2012-01-12 15:02 busables_unicorn -> /home/dtuite/dev/rails/busables/current/config/unicorn_init.sh
```

This script (which is appended to the bottom) essentially just runs the following command:

```
$APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production
```

where `$APP_ROOT` is the path to the root of my rails application. Every time that command is executed in that init.d script, it is supposed to do so as the `dtuite` (my deploy) user. To accomplish that, I call `su -c "$CMD" - dtuite` rather than just `$CMD`.

`/bin/unicorn` is a "binscript" which was generated by [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/) and `config/unicorn.rb` contains some configuration options which are passed to it.

The unicorn binscript looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'unicorn' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

load Gem.bin_path('unicorn', 'unicorn')
```

Now, I'm trying to start my unicorn service by running:

```
sudo service busables_unicorn start
```

That however produces the error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

I believe that this is happening because I'm running the service as the root user but RVM has installed ruby under the `dtuite` user's home directory and the root user has no access to it.

```
dtuite@localhost:$ which ruby
-> /home/dtuite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby
dtuite@localhost:$ su
Password: 
root@localhost:$ which ruby
root@localhost:$
```

**Question**
What do I need to do to make this work?

**My Setup**
 - ubuntu 11.10
 - ruby 1.9.3p0 (2011-10-30 revision 33570) [i686-linux]
 - nginx: nginx version: nginx/1.0.5

**What I've tried**

[rvmsudo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3644897/rvm-cannot-use-ruby-with-sudo)

```
$ rvmsudo service busables_unicorn start
/usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
```

[rvm-auto-ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819096/how-do-i-reference-the-local-ruby-in-a-hash-bang-executable)

```
$ sudo service cakes_unicorn start
-> [sudo] password for dtuite: 
-> -su: /home/dtuite/dev/rails/cakes/current/bin/unicorn: rvm-auto-ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230404/rvm-and-thin-root-vs-local-user) may help but to be honest I don't really understand it.

**Appendix**
The `busables_unicorn` script in it's entirety.

```
# INFO: This file is based on the example found at
# https://github.com/defunkt/unicorn/blob/master/examples/init.sh
# Modifications are courtesy of Ryan Bate's Unicorn Railscast
# Install Instructions:
# sudo ln -s full-path-to-script /etc/init.d/APP_NAME_unicorn
# Once installed, an app's unicorn can be reloaded by running
# sudo service APP_NAME_unicorn restart

#!/bin/sh
set -e
# Example init script, this can be used with nginx, too,
# since nginx and unicorn accept the same signals

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-60}

APP_ROOT=/home/dtuite/dev/rails/busables/current
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
# in order to access this, we need to first run
# 'bundle install --binstubs'. THis will fill our
# app/bin directory with loads of stubs for executables
# this is the command that is run when we run this script
CMD="$APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn -D -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E production"
# we don't need an init config because this file does it's job
action="$1"
set -u

old_pid="$PID.oldbin"

cd $APP_ROOT || exit 1

sig () {
    test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
    test -s $old_pid && kill -$1 `cat $old_pid`
}

case $action in
start)
    sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  # NOTE: We have to change all these lines.
  # Otherwise, the app will run as the root user
  su -c "$CMD" - dtuite
    ;;
stop)
    sig QUIT && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
force-stop)
    sig TERM && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Not running"
    ;;
restart|reload)
    sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
    echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  su -c "$CMD" - dtuite
    ;;
upgrade)
    if sig USR2 && sleep 2 && sig 0 && oldsig QUIT
    then
        n=$TIMEOUT
        while test -s $old_pid && test $n -ge 0
        do
            printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
        done
        echo

        if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $old_pid
        then
            echo >&2 "$old_pid still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
            exit 1
        fi
        exit 0
    fi
    echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  su -c "$CMD" - dtuite
    ;;
reopen-logs)
    sig USR1
    ;;
*)
    echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
    exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: If this is a production server, you should NOT be using Ruby based in a user's directory. What happens if that user makes a change? On a production server I'd install the one version of Ruby you need. And, users would not have accounts on it, only administrators.

Comment: It's a private production server. `dtuite` is me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like `su` isn't spawning a shell that reads the profile files that normally setup the rvm environment.

I'd try changing the command you run to

```
 source "/home/dtuite/.rvm/scripts/rvm" && $APP_ROOT/bin/unicorn...
```

Comment: Both this and Andrei S's answer both work. I tried this first so I guess I'll accept this one. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding your ruby path somewhere at the beginning of the start script, in an export statement like this:

`export PATH=/home/dtuite/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin:$PATH`